# Excel VBA Absolute Reference

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Very new to Excel. I have 3 Sheets in Excel. I'm trying to copy paste old values up one cell and lookup new values from another Sheet. My questions are

1. How do I reference the other sheet in the formula (see my Lookup section)
   For example, in the function that contains Match, I want to reference Sheets EDR rather than using 'for edr II'!
2. How do I use absolute reference?
   For example, I want to look up Column G in the Lookup Sheet instead of C[4]?

Very new to Excel, so I'd like to learn it in the proper way and know the rule of thumbs. Thank you

```
Sub EDRII()
    Dim EDR As Worksheet, Lookup As Worksheet, FA As Worksheet
    Set EDR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("for edr II")
    Set Lookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lookup")
    Set FA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FA_Segment_Region")

    'Copy & Paste Past Values
    EDR.Range("B6:X10").Value = EDR.Range("B5:X9").Value


   'Lookup Value from Lookup Tab
    EDR.Range("C10").FormulaR1C1 = _
       "=INDEX(Lookup!C[4],MATCH('for edr II'!R[-8]C[-1],Lookup!C[3],0))"
    EDR.Range("D10").FormulaR1C1 = _
       "=INDEX(Lookup!C[4],MATCH('for edr II'!R[-8]C[-2],Lookup!C[2],0))"
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at this [**`link`**](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vlookup-in-vba/).

Comment: Is this what your trying to do?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/42800024/4539709

Answer (score 0):

To specify absolute ranges, remove the square brackets. If the formula is referencing its own sheet you don't need the sheet name at all.

```
With EDR
    .Range("C10").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Lookup!C7,MATCH('" & .Name & "'!R[-8]C[-1],Lookup!C[3],0))"
    .Range("D10").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Lookup!C7,MATCH('" & .Name & "'!R[-8]C[-2],Lookup!C[2],0))"
End With
```