# Vba Excel do vlookup from a closed file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I would like to do a vlookup from a close file to an active open file, The path of the closed file will be given as a variant

Lets say       `mypath = "C:\list\...."`

I don't know if it is better to set the path only or the full-path (path+filename)

Could u please help ?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you want. If you want to access any file, you will need the full path and the filename. But you are free to save the path in one variable and the filename in another. Later on just use `mypath & myfile`. But this also depends on what you are going to do in detail.

Comment: I was from my mobile sorry for not providing more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need the full path.

Example

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Path As String

    Path = "C:\Temp\"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("B1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A1,'" & Path & "[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2'!A:J,3,FALSE)"
    End With
End Sub
```

*[VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)*

Comment: small contribution: And if you would like to get the path of your desktop you can simply call it with this code: `Dim yourdesktopaddress As String`
       `yourdesktopaddress = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")`  and even if you would like to get another folders' path on desktop you can simply add:   `& "\SpecificFolderOnTheDesktop"` after that code

Comment: @Mertinc post as second answer

Answer (score 2):

As long as @0m3r's solution answers the question here is a small contribution to anyone who is looking to reference a closed file located in **Desktop.**

> Even not specific for one user, works on any other user as well.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim yourdesktopaddress As String 

    yourdesktopaddress = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")

'or if you would like to reference another folder located in Desktop (i.e: SpecificFolderOnTheDesktop)
    'Dim folderinthedesktopaddress as String
    'folderinthedesktopaddress = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\SpecificFolderOnTheDesktop"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("B1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A1,'" & yourdesktopaddress & "[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2'!A:J,3,FALSE)"
    End With
End Sub
```