# VBA Code for Identifying if cell contains with loop

Tags: vba, excel

So currently I am trying to come up with a if statement. Basically if A3 has any text value I want it to equal awesome. I want to loop this command with the last column in mind.

```
Sub Criteria

    If Range("A2") = "Feedback" And Range("A3") = "**" Then
        Range("A1") = "Awesome"
    Else
        Range("A1") = ""
    End If

End sub
```

(This is the code I came up with can someone help me make it cleaner/faster)

```
Sub Status()

    lastrow = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow

        If Cells(i, 1) = "Onsite" And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then
            Cells(i, 3) = "Feedback"
        Else
            If Cells(i, 1) = "Phone" And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then
                Cells(i, 3) = "Feedback"
            Else
                If Cells(i, 1) = "Phone" And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then
                    Cells(i, 3) = "Pending Next Step"
                Else
                    If Cells(i, 1) = "Onsite" And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then
                        Cells(i, 3) = "Pending Decision"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is not working ?

Comment: It's working the way I need it to, but it just looks really ugly with all the End If. Push it will need to run through about 1000 rows. Afterwards there is another Sub procedure that will create the report<-This part I already have dow.

Comment: Use `Else If` (on the same line) and you need only one `End If`. also the first two tests can be reduced to one only. BTW this looks like a pretty simple formula without any VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try using [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) also set your worksheet so your not running the code on wrong sheet or to avoid a error*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Status()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each rng In Sht.Range("A2", Sht.Range("A9999").End(xlUp))
        Debug.Print rng.Address ' print on immed win
        DoEvents ' For Debuging

        If rng.Value = "Onsite" And rng.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
            rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Feedback"
        ElseIf rng.Value = "Onsite" And rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Pending Decision"
        End If

        If rng.Value = "Phone" And rng.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
            rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Feedback"
        ElseIf rng.Value = "Phone" And rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Pending Next Step"
        End If

    Next

    Set Sht = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

***[Range.Offset Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx)***

*Syntax: expression.Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)*

> *<sub>Returns a **[Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx)** object that represents a range that?s offset from the specified range.</sub>*

Comment: Thank you for the advice on setting the sheet. "rng.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0" Could you explain this part to me? There will always be a text value so does this function replace "IsEmpty".

Comment: rng.Offset(0,1) = column B, value > 0 = has value or is not empty

Comment: I will update with more help full links when I get back to my computer

Comment: Since I didn't give you more context it is not working how I need it to for my second problem. Column A that will never have blanks is why I created my macro referencing the first column. Column B will have missing values which will be the one I am going to be utilizing for the function. The numbers of rows I need to go through should equal to column A because I will be filling in the blanks for Column B with the value "Exclude" I already have my code set for my Pivot Table.

Comment: Actually, I was able to figure it out. Thank you for teaching me the offset function. It works really well. :)

Comment: Would you know how to do a formula based on the "rng'. For example         If rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" And rng.Value > 0 Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1) = rng.Formula = "=left(rng,find(""("",rng)-2)"

Comment: @AJ1225 just let me know if your need more help

Comment: you mean something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42800024/4539709

Comment: Yes. Similar to this, but I am getting "FALSE" for the value. I basically want it to do the formula referencing the range it is currently on. I would have thought "rng" would be equal to "A2", but that's not true.

Comment: If rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" And rng.Value > 0 Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1) = "=left(rng,find(""("",rng)-2)"

Comment: the formula would be  =(left ( A2, find(" (", A2)-2) . A2, for example, will have a value of Tony Smith (12090). The formula will make it Tony Smith and place it into B2.

Comment: I figured it out  If rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" And rng.Value > 0 Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1) = "=left(INDIRECT(""RC[-1]"",0),find(""("",INDIRECT(""RC[-1]"",0))-2)"

Comment: @AJ1225 `rng.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=(LEFT(RC[-1],FIND(""("",RC[-1])-2))"`

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I was able to apply it to the sheet I needed to. It probably saved me 30 minutes.