# Vlookup across multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

The idea behind this is to use vba **`vlookup`** on column G:AI from sheet11-13 to sheet1.  Header ends at row 3 across all worksheets.

I have written the codes as below. The code stops at the `ws1.Cells(r, c).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws1.Cells(r, 1).Value, ws2.Range("A1:AI500"), colnum, False)` showing subset out of range and sometimes even

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class.

Please advice on the way forward.

I Would like to send out files for better clarification but can't seem to find the attach function. Thank you !

```
Sub green_update()


Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet13")

Dim bil As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim for_col As Long, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, colnum As Long
r = 4: c = 7: colnum = 7

'mysheets = "sheet11:sheet12:sheet13"
'i would like to allow vlookup to search through all sheet 11-13

For for_col = 1 To ws2.Cells("4", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
lastrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For i = 1 To lastrow - 3

    ws1.Cells(r, c).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws1.Cells(r, 1).Value, ws2.Range("A1:AI500"), colnum, False)
    r = r + 1
    Next

 r = 4
 colnum = colnum + 1
 c = c + 1

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You said this is your code and if you don't know whether it works or not, how do we know that?

Comment: I think he tried to put some humour in his question @sktneer :). I don't know his workbook but probably he was missing because of his variables.

Comment: Simple example https://stackoverflow.com/a/42800024/4539709

Comment: @sktneer@0m3r Hi, would it be possible for me to contact anyone of you for help? Really do need a quick solution? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have totally changed what you were asking.. I am posting another answer to make it clear.
Still your request is not totally clear so that some inputs may refer to wrong destinations but you can change those ones easily. 
If you don't understand any part feel free to ask it again.

```
Option Explicit
Sub green_update()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Dim zaman As Double
 zaman = Timer
Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, wsNames as Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim colNo As Long, OthARowNo As Long, sh1ARowNo As Long
Dim for_col As Long, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, colnum As Long

r = 4: c = 7: colnum = 7

For Each wsNames In Sheets(Array("sheet11", "sheet12", "sheet13"))
    colNo = wsNames.Cells("4", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    'Column numbers are 35 but you are working between G:AI which is 29 columns!

    OthARowNo = wsNames.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    sh1ARowNo = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For for_col = 7 To colNo 'colNo Is 35 Green columns start at 7th column, totally 29 loop, till 35th one.
        For i = 1 To sh1ARowNo   'This should run until sh1's row number
            ws1.Cells(r, c).Value = Application.VLookup(ws1.Cells(r, 1).Value, wsNames.Range("A1:AI" & OthARowNo), colnum, False)
            If IsError(ws1.Cells(r, c).Value) Then
                ws1.Cells(r, c).Value = ""
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Next i
        r = 4
        colnum = colnum + 1
        c = c + 1
    Next for_col
    colnum = 7
    c = c + 6 'There are 6 columns between AI:AP and BR:BY
Next wsNames

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 MsgBox Format(Timer - zaman, "00.00") & "secs"
End Sub
```

Comment: I've used the codes and it is running. However, the columns are not completely filled as it stopped at column X. The vlookup function does not capture the data from the sheets 11-13. All I got was a standardized date "0/1/1990". And thank you for the last code, I would indeed like to capture the data from column number 7 from every sheet.

Comment: If it doesn't capture everything this is because of sheet1's D column's non-blank row number is probably less than other sheets row number. You can change that part to make it suitable for your sheet. As long as we can't predict and manage each detail of your workbook you have to try to figure out some of the details that you would like to change.

Comment: can I input a lastrow code here? lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).rowSo that it runs till the last row of column D then move to column E and so on?

Comment: The code I put there counts non-blank cells in D column. (it's again because of your first question and unclear explanation:).. ) But as I get ws 11-12-13 have more than what sheet1 D column has. So last row code won't work as well. You need to use wsNames' A column's row number I think.

Comment: @Carmen I'm not in my PC but edited my answer. Instead of sheet1's D column's row numbers now it will use wsNames (sheet11 12 or 13)'s related column's row number.

Comment: I've made changes accordingly and it still doesn't seem to work. Thank you for helping out! I'm working on creating a more detailed question. I would very much like to thank you for giving me a good start! :)

Comment: I'm sorry for the constant messages but I think I found the issue. When running the code, ws11 vlookup values are in the right place. But subsequently, ws12 and ws13 vlookup values are placed 7 columns to the left. Any recommendation? THANK YOU SO MUCH AGAIN. :)

Comment: What do you mean by 7 columns to the left @Carmen? If I will be able to understand you clearly glad to help you don't worry :)

Comment: I think because the code runs by worksheet, the first worksheet (ws11) runs perfectly whereby the vlookup values are at columns A:AI. When the code runs for the subsequent worksheets (ws12 & ws13), instead of starting from column A, it started at column AI(the end of ws11) for ws12 and column BS for ws13 (the end of ws12). And because the column index number started at 7, so it moved 7 columns to the left for ws12, then ws13. Maybe we should make ws12 and ws13 to start from column A?

Comment: That's not correct. `VLookup(ws1.Cells(r, 4).Value, wsNames.Range("A1:AI500"), colnum, False)
    If IsError(ws1.Cells(r, c).Value)`it looks for **A1:AI500** but looking for **colnum columns** of that range each time, do you want smth different? You are still not clear my friend. Send me your file otherwise it will never solved.

Comment: The colnum column vlookup range is correct as I needed it to look at that range across all ws each time. My problem now is, the vlookup values is not appearing in the right columns in ws1. When running the code, only vlookup values of ws11 is within the right columns (G:AI) but vlookup values of ws12 and ws13 is not. And because this is a loop, I was thinking ws11 vlookup values started from column A but ws12 and ws13 didn't start from column A hence the displacement of the vlookup values?

Comment: here is the link to my file. Thank you again for the help! https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygm1x6wog8pn9nx/vlookup%20online%20help.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: @carmen can you give me your email also. I solved your issue will update my answer when I get my PC.

Comment: @Carmen please see my edited answer. But as your loops are crowded, that one may take a bit long depends on your pc. (I also added msgbox that shows you how long did it take to run whole code). And please don't forget to accept the answer! After you do it then I'll also send you an email. Cheers :)

Comment: @Carmen Hey Carmen please approve answer as an accepted. I spent few days to answer your question!

Answer (score 1):

I explained my answer within the code, but to summarize your problems:

**1-** You don't define your variables, especially worksheets. Never Assume your worksheet and always define and set references to Workbooks and Worksheets

**2-** You are limiting your `For loops` with the Row number of A column and Column number of 3rd row, but what if they are empty or not compatible with your lookup rounds? Then you may get error or wrong results. Define them carefully.

```
Option Explicit

Sub green_update()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change this Sheet1 name with your current Worksheet name
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("mysheets")

Dim bil As String 'I don't know where do you use that variable.
Dim lastrow As Long 'Prefer to work with Long instead of Integer
Dim for_col As Long, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, colnum As Long
r = 4: c = 7: colnum = 7


     For for_col = 1 To ws2.Cells("4", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'This is important! Here in this case are you sure you, _ 
'you would like to define how many times your For loop will run based on 3rd row?     

lastrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'This is also important! Are you sure you would like to run your For loop_
'based on the row number of A column? I think you should define it -3 _
'because you start your lookup from D4 (so first 3 one Is not necessary)

        For i = 1 To lastrow - 3
            ws1.Cells(r, c).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws1.Cells(r, 4).Value, ws2.Range("A1:AI500"), colnum, False)
            r = r + 1
        Next
 r = 4
 colnum = colnum + 1
 c = c + 1

     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: would it be better if i defined it this way? I'm pretty new at this and would love to get the guidance. So the main objective is to get information from column G to AI from 3 separate sheets to 1 main sheet.  
I would like to loop the entire vlookup formula from top to bottom, then left to right from column G to column AI. My header stops at row 3 and hence the subsequent available line is row 4. 
I have incorporated your solution, but at line
 For for_col = 1 To ws.Cells("3", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
it shows that "Object is required" when I run it.

Comment: @Carmen you should look at the **VBA Best Practices** which helped me/ and still helping me a lot.[https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices#t=201705250528371943986]

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! Will definitely look at it. But for the mean time, any other advice to solve the current string? Really do need a quick solution for this. :)

Comment: @Carmen, you haven't mention anything like *3 separate sheets to 1 main sheet* in your question, so that my answer only looks for "mysheets" Sheet and bring the values to Sheet1. 
For the error line, that's why I wrote an important notice. But what I understood now is, your loop should be repeated until the column number of "mysheet" Sheet. 
So try this one `For for_col = 1 To ws2.Cells("4", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` instead of `For for_col = 1 To ws.Cells("3", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: Ah sorry, instead of ws1 and ws2 I wrote ws to some parts. That's why you got an error. Please see edited answer now. The important point is does your `"mysheet"` sheet has full columns in `4th row`? and full rows in `A column`?

Comment: I've made the changes but now it is showing the "unable to get the vlookup property at  [code] ws1.Cells(r, c).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws1.Cells(r, 1).Value, ws2.Range("A1:AI500"), colnum, False) [Code] . Also, for mysheets, I've done the combination like this [CODE] mysheets = "sheet11:sheet12:sheet13"[CODE]. Would this is enable the vlookup to look through all these sheets? @mertinc

Comment: No it does not. And that's  why code is not working because you don't have a sheet named `mysheets` ... I wish you would say this at first...

Comment: I'm sorry. Still trying to figure my way in this.  But even when I set ws2 =wb.sheets("Name") and changed the vlookup line accordingly, it shows that it's unable to get vlookup property. How would you advise going forward? I was thinking to have 3 separate vlookup lines for all 3 different sheets and run them. Would that be possible? Or is there a way for me to allow vlookup to run on all 3 sheets with a formula? Sorry again and thank you :) @mertinc

Comment: You said Sheet11 - 12 -13 in your previous comment and now you are telling "Name" , are you working with CodeNames or Sheet Names or what? Sorry Carmen its becoming more difficult after your each new comment :) Try to upload your file somewhere otherwise I can't help you anymore.

Comment: I have edited the question for better understanding. I'm sorry again for the confusion. I can't seem to upload the file anywhere. Any advice?@mertinc

Comment: I would like to share with you the dropbox link if possible. Please do advice. :)