# Create a new file in any desktop using an excel file with a command button to execute that task

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file, BookDatabase.xls, which holds a database of books and has a command button that backup some contents of a worksheet to a new excel file.

My problem is BookDatabase.xls will be used in a laptop and a desktop, how can I make this button to work in both devices.

Below is my portion of my code for the creation of the file and I'm expecting that this will not work in the other device because the path is only for the desktop.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Karen\Documents\BookDatabase.xls"
```

I'm not very good with VBA and would like to learn more. I hope you can also place a comment in the code so the I could better understand the function of the code lines.

Comment: https://ss64.com/vb/special.html

Comment: Are you certain the path is not the same?  What is the path you need for your laptop.  What you show is fairly generic for Windows, and, unless your laptop has been set up in an unusual way, or if your Username is not `Karen` on the laptop, the path should be OK.

Comment: The Username in the laptop is not Karen.

Comment: Look at @Mertinc answer here's https://stackoverflow.com/a/44172883/4539709

Comment: @Tim Williams, thank you for he reference, I'm studying it now.

Comment: @0m3r, thank you too for the link, your idea is similar with Tim Williams', I'll use it as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is only that the User Name is not the same on the laptop, the following should work:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\BookDatabase.xls"
```