# vlookup on excel vba throws error 400

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am trying to retrieve "name" in the sheet "Properties" but I keep getting the error 400 whenever I try to run it.

I am able to retrieve each individual content by a MsgBox, but I just don't know why this Vlookup statement throws me an error 400.

```
temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, 
           currentWb.Worksheets("Properties").Range("B2:C11"), 2, False)
```

This is how I set name:
`name = Wb.Worksheets("Sample").Cells(rrow, 9).Value`
where "rrow" is my for loop.

And this is how i declare my temp:`Dim temp As String`

Anybody has any idea why ? Is it something to do with the syntax ?

Comment: What is the value of your `name` variable?  Are you sure that that value exists somewhere in `Properties!B2:B11`?  Perhaps show us the code where you are setting `name` and where you are declaring `name` and `temp`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42800024/4539709

Comment: @YowE3K i have edited my question. I am 200% sure the value exists somewhere in B2:C11. I have checked countless times.

Comment: And your `currentWb` object is definitely referring to the workbook that contains your "Properties" worksheet?

Comment: Yes. Check and verified many times too

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your line of code as far as I can see (other than the fact that it is on two lines without a line continuation character, but I assume that's just a posting issue) so all I can suggest is that you stop your code just before it crashes and then use the Immediate Window to check things like `?currentWb.Worksheets("Properties").Range("B2:C11").Address`, `?name`, and if your value should, for instance, match with cell B5 something like `?name = currentWb.Worksheets("Properties").Range("B5").Value`.  Hopefully one of those tests will give us a clue as to what is wrong.

Comment: when I run your code it works just fine. what kind of values do you have for `name` ? how is `name` defined ?