# Using VBA Vlookup to work between two sheets and fill a whole column

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I need to code this **`VLOOKUP`** macro to read from:

Column `(A:B)` of the "Reach" sheet, and then apply those values into

Column `"L"` of the `"TV"` sheet using Column `"A"` as a unique identifier.

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Reach!A:B,2,FALSE)` would be the code Excel code I would enter into Column `"L"`  of the `"TV"` Sheet.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TV")
    .Range("L2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Reach!A:B,2,FALSE)"
End With
```

This is the code that I have tried, but it only fills in the L2 cell.

How would I get this to apply to the whole column?

Comment: `"L2:L"` is not a valid range in Excel.  Did you mean `"L2:L" & lr`?  (P.S. A problem description of "it's not working" is likely to attract downvotes.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42800024/4539709

Comment: @0m3r I've managed to just fill the L2 cell, how would i get it to fill out the rest of the "L" column? Would i have to use a for loop?

Comment: @Anon - See my first comment - your original code was so close I didn't bother to post it as an answer, it seemed more like a typo

Comment: @YowE3K yeah i tried adding the lr, but it gave me a mismatch error.

Comment: What data type is `lr`??  It was a `Long`, so that should have been able to be converted to a `String` and successfully concatenated to `"L2:L"`.

Comment: @YowE3K got some troubles in the past with that.... but I'm not able to recreate it... so you are fully right with that. Learned something new again, thanks :)

Comment: @DirkReichel Being on SO has ensured that I learn a **minimum** of one new thing every day!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.

This will fill L to the last row of Data in A, I chose A because that is what you are looking up:

```
.Range("L2:L" & .Range("A" & .Rows.count).end(xlup).row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Reach!A:B,2,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 3):

In the original version of this question you showed the following code:

```
Dim lr As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TV")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("L2:L") = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Reach!A:B,2,FALSE),0"
End With
```

If you fix the invalid range `"L2:L"` by changing it to `"L2:L" & lr` (and changing `Range` to `.Range` so that it is equivalent to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TV").Range`) your code should work:

```
Dim lr As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TV")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("L2:L" & lr) = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Reach!A:B,2,FALSE)"
End With
```

(Well, it should work as long as column M is the correct column to use when checking for the last row.  Personally, I would have checked using column A, because the formula you are using seems to imply that there will be a value in column A for every row you want to include this formula in column L for.)

Note: I just noticed you had a stray `,0` on the end of your original formula - that would have caused an issue too.  I have removed it as well.

Comment: I still get a 1004 error on the .Range("L2:L" & lr) = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Reach!A:B,2,FALSE),0" line. I've also tried to check using column A.

Comment: @Anon Yes - I just noticed that stray `,0` - get rid of it as it makes the formula invalid.

Comment: that works! thanks so much for your time! i really appreciate it