# Vlookup Macro Erroring Out

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Below is my **`vlookup`** code for my **macro** and I keep getting an error on the text inside the *.

I am trying to use a `vlookup` that will see the random word selected with another button and pull the definition.

Adding in regular `vlookup` code in Excel: **`=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!A2:B500,2,FALSE)`**

```
Sub Definition2()

Dim lookupvalue As Variant
Dim lookuprange As Variant

lookupvalue = Sheet2.Range("B2").Value
Set lookuprange = Sheet1.Range("A2:B500")

'- 2: execute vlookup functionwith variables above -'
vresult = Application.VLookup(lookupvalue, lookuprange, 2, False)

Range("J3").Value = vresult

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42800024/4539709

Comment: Does the lookup work as a formula in the sheet?

Comment: Yea my VLookup formula in excel works great but my button just isn’t returning the correct value, instead it returns n/a

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Instead of specifying the range with the rows set the vlookuprange as the whole column

**FIRST ANSWER**

You can't "set" a variable declared as a string since is not an object

```
Sub Definition2()

Dim lookupvalue As String
Dim lookuprange As Range
Dim lookupcolnum As Single

lookupvalue = Sheet2.Range("B3").Value
Set lookuprange = Sheet1.Range("A:B")

'- 2: execute vlookup functionwith variables above -'
vresult = Application.VLookup(lookupvalue, lookuprange, 2, False)

Range("J3").Value = vresult

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, i no longer get the error but i return N/A now instead of the definition

Comment: If you get N/A is because the look up value is not found in the look up range :)

Comment: thats where i am confused! if i do a regular vlookup in excel with the same look up value and range i return the value i need but i cant get it to return the value with the vba coding

Comment: Record a macro using the regular vlookup and update your question with the code, your syntax or data might need to be modified

Comment: I updated my answer, try setting the vlookrange using the columns only, check my answer!

Comment: appreciate your help, setting the vlookuprange to A:B didnt return the value either