# How to reference a cell in another workbook that is closed (using INDIRECT function)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to reference a cell in a closed workbook by using the indirect function. I have tried the following:

```
= INDIRECT("'C:\Users\Ross\Desktop\["&A1&"]" & B3 & "'!$A$2")
```

A1 is my file name, B3 is sheet name, A2 is cell reference.

I tried for awhile to get it to work by using other stackoverflow questions but it keeps throwing a #ref error.

I would like to use the indirect function but if VBA is required I'd love to see what you did to make it work.

Any and all help is appreciated!

[image: A picture of my workbook that I am using is attached]

Comment: INDIRECT only works with open workbooks.

Comment: @urdearboy https://superuser.com/questions/535871/indirect-gives-a-ref-error-for-reference-to-external-workbook-where-making-a-d

Comment: @urdearboy close the target workbook and hit F9 to calculate.  It will turn to `@REF!`  I have Office 365 Excel and it still does it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help -see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42799757/4539709

Comment: @ross-leavitt: you may be able to use [MoreFunc XL Addin](https://ccm.net/download/download-24205-morefunc-macro-add-in-for-excel) which includes an `INDIRECT.EXT` function that works with closed workbooks...

Answer (score 0):

Indirect references open workbooks which means you dont need the file reference. rewritten as = INDIRECT("'["&A1&"]" & B3 & "'!$A$2")

That being said, you must have the data open so it is available for indirect to call on it. 
If you're opening the file often or every time you open the workbook containing the INDIRECT function in question, I suggest making a simple batch file to open them both.